# T-SQL STRING_AGG problems dunno if bad writing or just not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, string-agg

How come i don't see the seperation  off my  i.inventoryId  in first part ?
but when i select them in a other  select i  get way more results. 
also 'Jedi' == (PlayerAvatarId 6)

https://i.ibb.co/XW4NJC7/image.png

```
SELECT p.FirstName [Spelers Voornaam]
    ,p.LastName [Spelers Achternaam]
    ,pa.AvatarName [Spelers Avatarnaam]
    ,pa.FamilyName [Familie's Groeps Naam]
    ,Av.Type [Avatar's Type]
    ,string_agg (i.InventoryId, ',') as [In Inventory]

FROM Player AS p
LEFT JOIN PlayerAvatar AS pa ON p.PlayerId = pa.PlayerId
LEFT JOIN Avatar AS Av ON pa.AvatarId = Av.AvatarId
LEFT JOIN Avatar AS a ON pa.AvatarId = a.AvatarId
LEFT JOIN Inventory as i on  i.InventoryId = pa.InventoryId
LEFT JOIN Item as it on it.ItemId = i.ItemId
WHERE pa.AvatarName = 'Jedi'
GROUP BY p.FirstName, p.LastName, pa.AvatarName, pa.FamilyName, av.Type, i.InventoryId

SELECT *
from Inventory
Where PlayerAvatarId = 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want to group by InventoryId if that's what you're concatenating... Try this:

Edit, you need to remove columns that are different from row-to-row.

```
SELECT p.FirstName [Spelers Voornaam]
    ,p.LastName [Spelers Achternaam]
    ,pa.FamilyName [Familie's Groeps Naam]
    ,string_agg (i.InventoryId, ',') as [In Inventory]
FROM Player AS p
LEFT JOIN PlayerAvatar AS pa ON p.PlayerId = pa.PlayerId
LEFT JOIN Avatar AS Av ON pa.AvatarId = Av.AvatarId
LEFT JOIN Avatar AS a ON pa.AvatarId = a.AvatarId
LEFT JOIN Inventory as i on  i.InventoryId = pa.InventoryId
LEFT JOIN Item as it on it.ItemId = i.ItemId
GROUP BY p.FirstName, p.LastName, pa.AvatarName, pa.FamilyName, av.Type
```

Or you can aggregate those columns too.

```
SELECT p.FirstName [Spelers Voornaam]
    ,p.LastName [Spelers Achternaam]
    ,string_agg(pa.AvatarName,',') [Spelers Avatarnaam]
    ,pa.FamilyName [Familie's Groeps Naam]
    ,string_agg(Av.Type,',') [Avatar's Type]
    ,string_agg (i.InventoryId, ',') as [In Inventory]

FROM Player AS p
LEFT JOIN PlayerAvatar AS pa ON p.PlayerId = pa.PlayerId
LEFT JOIN Avatar AS Av ON pa.AvatarId = Av.AvatarId
LEFT JOIN Avatar AS a ON pa.AvatarId = a.AvatarId
LEFT JOIN Inventory as i on  i.InventoryId = pa.InventoryId
LEFT JOIN Item as it on it.ItemId = i.ItemId
GROUP BY p.FirstName, p.LastName, pa.FamilyName,
```

Comment: Still does only show 5 in the [in inventory]  need to show at least 9 different  records  see my screenshot of me just selecting the inventory items

Comment: Then I would bet that one of the other columns should be removed. Remove `WHERE pa.AvatarName = 'Jedi'` and post the sample data. Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/269b5/3/0) that depicts it should work as long as you have the correct groupings.

Comment: sorry mate im pretty new"noob" in sql  and don't realy understand what you want in that fiddle. If you wanne see my project  check my github https://github.com/janmoenens/database
everything is there  but  all my writing is in  dutch.  but if you  go into my examenDatabase folder everything you need  shoud be there also if you like you can build it youreself. 
this project im making is for my sql exam

Comment: Looking at your github data... For `PlayerId = 31` there are three different `AvatarName` values - Jedi, Jedi2, Jedi3... And three different `Type`s - WARLOCK, HUNTER, WARRIOR... If this is the same data that you're using, this would be one of the problems I see. See my edit above.

Comment: Ty indeed this works a bit more then expected but it works :D ty